# Two equal distribution share the same property.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

It may be an idiot question but it really has bothered me for a long time.

For two distributions (generalized functions) $u,v \in \mathcal{D}'(
\mathbb{R}^n)$, if $u=v$ in the distributional sense (i.e. for any test function $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)=C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),$ we have $(u,\phi)_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}=(v,\phi)_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}.$)  Now if we know that $v$ is also in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (square integrable function) ,can we deduce that $u$ is also in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

First, if I know $v$ is a distribution and additionally $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),$ for any test function $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is $(v,\phi)_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}$ must be written as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} v(x)\phi(x)dx$? Besides, how can I deduce the property of distribution $u$?

Comment: In order to make this question well-posed you should specify what you mean by $u \in L^2$ when $u$ is a priori only a distribution (and I think this is where your confusion really is). The sensible definition of that would be that there exists an $f \in L^2$ such that $(u, \phi) = \int f(x) \phi(x) dx$ for all test functions $\phi$ (i.e. $u$ lies in the image of $L^2$ in $D'$ under the usual inclusion of the former into the latter). With this definition, answering your question should be straight forward.

Comment: Your explanation is so clear! Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting again. I have an another very similar question. If there is a sequence of function $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $L^2,$ and I also know that $u_n$ converges to $v$ in $H^{-1/2}$ (The real index Sobolev space defined by Fourier transform, to be exact, $H^{-1/2}=\{ \mathcal{S}': \int (1+|\xi|^2)^{-1/2}||\hat{u}(\xi)|^2<\infty.\}$)  Can I show that $v$ also belongs to $L^2$?

Comment: Since $u=v$ in tempered distribution space $\mathcal{S}'$, and denoted the injection from $L^2$ into $\mathcal{S}'$ by $i,$ then $<v,\phi>=<i(u),\phi>=\int u\phi,$ by your defnition, $v \in L^2$. However, it is possible to show that $\int |\hat{v}|^2<\infty$? I am very confused here since the latter expression looks like definition for a "realistic function" which can be integrated. And your definition is for the "generalized function" which are only defined abstractly.

Comment: First notice that the fourier transform is a map from $\mathcal{S}'$ to $\mathcal{S}'$. Part of the definition of $u \in H^{-s}$ is that $\hat{u} \in \mathcal{S}'$ is represented by a function (which is not for free). It's therefore not clear to me that your expression is in any sense a more "realistic" definition. 

However, If you work with the function $\hat{v}$, seeing that $\int |\hat{v}|^2$ is finite is not so hard. Indeed, $\hat{u}_n \to \hat{u}$ in $L^2$, so you only need to see that $\hat{u} = \hat{v}$ almost everywhere. For this use that $u_n \to u$ in $H^{-1/2}$ also.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. "Realistic" function means a function can be defined pointwise. I have been reckoning that $\hat{u},\hat{v}$ are tempered distributions then what is the meaning of $\int |\hat{u}|^2 d\xi$? After your explanation, I knew that $\hat{u}$ is in $L_{\text{loc}}^1 \cap \mathcal{S}',$ which means its Fourier transform is a function defined pointwise.